# Is it possible to typeset the input file path next to each line as lineno package does with line numbers?

Tags: line-numbering

I am imagining a very tiny source file path (perhaps from the `currfile` package, and very tiny because paths *could* be long and there is not much room in a margin) next to each line similar to the way the `lineno` package adds lines to each line with `\linenumbers` as debugging tool. A PDF can be scaled large enough to view the tiny text, and the size would not need to conform to printer capabilities or ideal font sizes.

Obviously, a line may contain more than one source, therefore a semi-accurate/decent solution would be to only use the first token of each line, for example.

Come to think of it, I do not know how to reference lines in the output. I only know of `\the\inputlineno`.